# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `emails_path' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I'm making a simple email registration form in rails but I got stuck in this error.

I have generate controller Emails and Model Email with only email field in Email Model.

here is my controller with method new

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController
 def new
  @email = Email.new
  end
end
```

below is my view which is very simple

```
<h2>Register Email</h2>

<% form_for(@email) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>
 </div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Now I have defined the routes using rake routes

which was working fine until I added code in controller and html page

In routes.rb
I defined path for root as this

```
root 'emails#new'
```

and my rake routes looks like this

```
       emails_new GET    /emails/new(.:format)             emails#new
       home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)             home#index
       root GET    /                                 emails#new
```

Now I get this error

```
   ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `emails_path' for   #<#<Class:0x007f25edc36a58>:0x007f25edc4ffa8>):
  App 4103 stderr:     1: <h2>Register Email</h2>
   App 4103 stderr:     2: 
App 4103 stderr:     3: <% form_for(@email) do |f| %>
App 4103 stderr:     4:   <div class="field">
App 4103 stderr:     5:     <%= f.label :email %><br />
App 4103 stderr:     6:     <%= f.text_field :email %>
App 4103 stderr:   app/views/emails/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_emails_new_html_erb___4438819380742713977_69900439838140'
```

any help thanks

Comment: Can you try

`form_for @email, :url => emails_new_path do |f|`

Comment: now error is gone, but fileds are not visible except heading Register Email

Comment: Can you post the fields of **emails** table

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I can't comment. Your missing `=` in your form_for.

It must be `<%= form_for ...%>`

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have route for actually creating `email` record. You can use [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default):

```
resources :emails, only: [:new, :create] # <-- list of actions you need
```

Also, of course, you should prepend your `form_for` call with `<%=` to to put the result of this call in your HTML.